# Почему модераторы удалили мой ответ?

Tags: обсуждение, поддержка, модерация

Почему модераторы позволяют себе без объяснения причин удалять сообщения людей, которые ничего не нарушают?

Речь конкретно про [это](https://prnt.sc/tlw63j) сообщение.

Почему некоторые люди не могут высказывать своё мнение? Разве не в этом суть меты?

Comment: Считаю, что данная лексика просто неуместна на этом сайте. Используйте какие-то другие выражения для описания ситуации. Желательно также подкреплять их фактами

Comment: @Miron укажите, пожалуйста - какая конкретно лексика неуместна? По каким параметрам она не проходит?

Comment: @СергейВалерьевич "инфантилы"

Comment: Я спрашивал у Мирона

Answer (score 8):

Этот ответ необъективен, оскорбителен для сообщества, по сути в нем даже нет ответа нa заданный вопрос, зато очень много оскорблений.
Как минимум я (но я думаю и другие тоже) поставил на этот вопрос тревогу:

> **невежливый или оскорбительный**
> *Содержимое данного сообщения неуместно в контексте уважительной беседы.*

Модераторы просто среагировали: посчитали тревогу полезной и удалили сообщение.

---

По пунктам:

- > Почему модераторы позволяют себе без объяснения причин удалять сообщения людей, которые ничего не нарушают?

  Вы нарушили правило, оскорбив сообщество. Объяснить причину они не обязаны.
- > Почему некоторые люди не могут высказывать свое мнение?

  Каждый участник сообщества имеет право высказывать свое мнение, если оно не нарушает Code of Conduct
- > Или это такой показушный ресурс, для создания видимости, что сообщество что-то решает.

  На это я отвечать не буду — это просто провокация.
- > Где можно выражать любое мнение (но только если оно совпадает с мнением администрации)?

  Здесь, но опять же таки без оскорблений.

Comment: Это просто неспособность принимать чужое мнение

Comment: @СергейВалерьевич _Каждый_ участник сообщества имеет право высказывать свое мнение, если оно не нарушает Code of Conduct

Comment: На что конкретно оскорбилось сообщество?

Comment: @СергейВалерьевич Как минимум на "инфантилов".

Comment: @СергейВалерьевич Нечего сказать? Ну так я ответил на ваш вопрос или нет? Если да, то по правилам вам следует пометить его галочкой.

Comment: Разве "инфантилы" - это оскорбление? К тому же - я не говорил, что в сообществе находятся только инфантилы

Comment: @СергейВалерьевич Докажите обратное.

Comment: Логика уровня "Бога нет. Бога съел кот-богоед. А ты докажи, что кота-богоеда не существует"

Comment: @СергейВалерьевич Wikipedia: `незрелость в развитии, сохранение в поведении или физическом облике черт, присущих предшествующим возрастным этапам` — когда участник назвал вас "малолетним долботрясом", вы обиделись и написали в комментах, что это не правильно. Я разделил вашу позицию и плюсанул коммент т.к. я стараюсь быть не предвзятым. Модераторы вырезали из ответа упоминание об "малолетнем долботрясе". Теперь вы по сути назвали примерно таким же оскорблением все сообщество.

Comment: Я ведь не называл никого инфантилом. Я сказал, что инфантилам нравятся циферки. Нужно это учитывать

Comment: @СергейВалерьевич Это субъективное суждение, не подкрепленное никакими доказательствами или примерами было использовано для попытки нанесения оскорбления сообществу.

Comment: @СергейВалерьевич Простите, я не понял что именно вы хотите сказать. Вы утверждаете, что в сообществе есть инфантилы? Или может конкретно я воспринимаю это на свой счет и тут вы скрыто называете меня инфантилом?

Comment: @СергейВалерьевич поверьте, всем всё равно на то, что вы хотите, только если это не полезно обществу. То, что вы делаете не полезно обществу. Почему? Инфа по-всюду)

Answer (score 3):

Всё очень просто: ваше мнение не входит в нормы этого сайта. Да, я, конечно, понимаю, что в "свободном" обществе каждый может высказывать что хочет, но реальность такова, что есть объективные факторы (*бытие*), которые формируют *сознание* общества, и в нём устанавливается большинство и меньшинства. В SO вполне нормальное бытие и оно не нуждается в корректировке. Это мы можем понять по некоторым принципам сознания данного общества:

- Не оскорблять других участников SO
- Стремление объективности
- Стремление к научности и логичности
- Приветствуется структурированная информация

Я не вижу в этом ничего плохого. Просто вы принадлежите к тому меньшинству, которое хочет полной анархии и свободы слова всем и каждому.

И да, я за свободу слова, но "твоя свобода слова заканчивается там, где начинается моя". Наше тело и личность – это наша *личная* собственность, и будьте добры, оставьте нашу собственность в покое от субъективных мнений.

Я спокойно могу воспринять *объективную* *критику*, но только не *субъективные* *оскорбления*.

Comment: Стремление объективности = ru.stackoverflow :^)  Стремление к научности и логичности = ru.stackoverflow :^)  , а что такое научность ??? это когда хвалятся какие они крутые и у них по 200 диссертаций ???

Comment: @timob256 возможно у нас разные SO, вам виднее... Научность тоже самое что и логичность. Просто использовал 2 синонима. Возможно у вас учёные (учёные "вообще") это только те, кто "хвалятся какие они крутые и у них по 200 диссертаций", опять же, у нас разная наука и учёные.

Comment: не спорю признаю :3  , тут есть элемент"  вкусовщины "